# Gruntfile.js error on windows

Tags: javascript, sass, gruntjs

I am following this tutorial [Link](https://markgoodyear.com/2013/07/automating-your-workflow-with-grunt/). I am using a windows PC

My SASS version is 3.4.16

This is my Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Read package.json
  grunt.file.readJSON('package.json');

  //Initialize grunt
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Sass task
    sass: {

      // Sass development options
      dev: {
        options: {
          style: 'expanded',
        },
        files: {
          'css/main.css': 'css/sass/dev.scss'
        }
      },

      // Sass distribution options
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'compressed'
        },
        files: {
          'css/main.css': 'css/sass/main.scss'
        }
      }
    },

  });



  // Load tasks
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');


  // Create Default Task
  grunt.registerTask('dev', [
    'sass:dev' // Compile Sass with dev settings
  ]);

  // Create Distribution Task
  grunt.registerTask('dist', [
    'sass:dist' // Compile Sass with distribution settings
  ]);
}
```

When I reun this code i get an error as

> Running "sass:dist" (sass) task Errno::ENOENT: No such file or
>   directory @ rb_sysopen - undefined   Use --trace for backtrace.
>   Warning: Exited with error code 1 Use --force to continue.

Could someone please help me with this.

Comment: Have you got ruby installed/compass? If grunt-contrib-sass is using Compass it might be having a problem with this issue. https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1918

Comment: @EdwardKnowles Thanks for the comment. I have installed compass :)